# Check integer value in Unity for player turn

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to prevent a click if a move is invalid based on an the int lastClickedValuex and o respectively

Not sure how to do the check.  Last thing I have to do before my code is complete and driving me insane.

Basically

```
if (lastclickedvaluex >= boardsquarevalue || boardsquarevalue == 0){
    allow move;
} else {
    dont show the sprite;
    dont switch turns;
    restart the players turn;
    dont change the value of lastclickedvaluex;
    make like player never clicked I suppose;
}
```

Im at hour 20 so its probably something immensely stupid.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{

public int playerTurn;   //0 = X && 1 = O
public int turnCountX;     //Tally Player X Turns
public int turnCountO;     //Tally Player O Turns
public GameObject[] bigTurnIcons;  //Player Icons Array
public Sprite[] playerGamePieces;      //GamePieces Array
public Button[] gameBoardSquares;  //GameBoard Array
public int lastPlayedSquareValueX;  //Store Value of Last Clicked Square
public int lastPlayedSquareValueO;  // ""
public bool gameOver;  // End Game
public bool isValidMove;  //  Check For Valid Move
public int boardSquareValue;  //Value of Each Square from Value Script 
public int[] markedSquare;    //Win Check Array

void Awake()
{
    GameSetup();
}

public void GameSetup()
{
    isValidMove = true;
    playerTurn = 0;  //Set Player Turn To X Goes First
    turnCountX = 0;    //Set X Turn Count to 0
    turnCountO = 0;    //Set O Turn COunt to 0
    bigTurnIcons[0].SetActive(true);  //Set X Turn Icon to Active
    bigTurnIcons[1].SetActive(false); //Set O Turn Icon to Inactive
    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoardSquares.Length; i++)  //Initialize Squares (GameBoard) Array
    {
        gameBoardSquares[i].interactable = true;  //Make All Squares Clickable
        gameBoardSquares[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = null;  //Set TurnIcons To Off

    }
    for (int j = 0; j < markedSquare.Length; j++)  //Initialize MarkedSquare Array
    {
        markedSquare[j] = -100;  //Set Value To Wacky Number So It Doesn't Interfere With Formula FOr Win Check
    }
}

public void PlaySquareButton(int WhichNumber)  //OnClick Function
{


    markedSquare[WhichNumber] = playerTurn + 1; //OnClick Store Which PLayer Clicked Which Square
    gameBoardSquares[WhichNumber].image.sprite = playerGamePieces[playerTurn]; //OnClick Check To Place Correct Symbol (GamePiece)
    gameBoardSquares[WhichNumber].interactable = false;  //OnClick Set Button.Interactable To False So It Cannot Be CLicked Again
    boardSquareValue = gameBoardSquares[WhichNumber].GetComponent<Value>().boardSquareValue; //OnClick Set The Square's Value To The BoardSquareValue Variable in the Value Script

    if (turnCountO > 3 || turnCountX > 3)  //Check For Wins After 3 Turns
    {
        CheckForWinner();  //Iterate Through The MarkedSpaces Array To Check For A Winner
    }

    if (playerTurn == 0)

    {

        playerTurn = 1;                      //Player O Turn
        bigTurnIcons[0].SetActive(false);
        bigTurnIcons[1].SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log(boardSquareValue);           //Show Value of Clicked Square in Console
        lastPlayedSquareValueX = boardSquareValue;   //Set Last CLicked Value to Current Clicked Square
        turnCountX++;    //Increment Player Turn Count

    }
    else
    {

        playerTurn = 0;
        bigTurnIcons[0].SetActive(true);
        bigTurnIcons[1].SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log(boardSquareValue);
        lastPlayedSquareValueO = boardSquareValue;
        turnCountO++;
    }

}
```

Thank you for any help

[GameBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwzJl.png)

Comment: But what happens now? How does your code behave and how you would like it behave instead?

Comment: It does everything its supposed to.  When a square is clicked it puts the players gamepiece in the square and stores the value of the square in the lastclickedvalue variable.  If the value of the square of their next click is less than the lastclickedvalue, it is an invalid move and they should have to choose another square.  Currently the sprite appears, the console spits out the value of the boardSquareValue int, it stores the boardSquareValue into lastclickedvalue each turn.  Just missing the you cant do that part.  Everything Ive tried makes most functionality not work.

Comment: Can you add any image or similar of your board? In what axis progress the squares (Horizontal/Vertical)?

Comment: Added Image, Diagonal Only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, you may be missing:

```
public PlaySquareButton(int WhichNumber){


    if(playerTurn)
    {
        if(WhichNumber > lastPlayedSquareValueX){
            markedSquare[WhichNumber] = playerTurn + 1; //OnClick Store Which PLayer Clicked Which Square
            gameBoardSquares[WhichNumber].image.sprite = playerGamePieces[playerTurn]; //OnClick Check To Place Correct Symbol (GamePiece)
            gameBoardSquares[WhichNumber].interactable = false;  //OnClick Set Button.Interactable To False So It Cannot Be CLicked Again
            ...

        }
    }else{
        if(WhichNumber > lastPlayedSquareValueO){
            markedSquare[WhichNumber] = playerTurn + 1; //OnClick Store Which PLayer Clicked Which Square
            gameBoardSquares[WhichNumber].image.sprite = playerGamePieces[playerTurn]; //OnClick Check To Place Correct Symbol (GamePiece)
            gameBoardSquares[WhichNumber].interactable = false;  //OnClick Set Button.Interactable To False So It Cannot Be CLicked Again
            ...

        }
    }

}
```

Basically before you start your functionality you check if the WhichNumber, that I guess comes from the square once clicked, is greater than the lastPlayedSquareValueX

Comment: Didnt Work.  First Click Adds No Piece.  Second the second players piece appears, then first player as normal and so on.  Doesnt prevent adding to squares of lower value though.

Comment: So it worked for the first player, but not for the second player? That may be because it is necessary to check as well lastPlayedSquareValueO. Confirm me that for the first one worked

Comment: And also tell me, what is the meaning of WhichNumber

Comment: Fiddled with moving things around.  Got there with what you provided

Comment: boardSquareValue = gameBoardSquares[WhichNumber].GetComponent<Value>().boardSquareValue; //OnClick Set The Square's Value To The BoardSquareValue Variable in the Value Script
        if (lastPlayedSquareValueX <= boardSquareValue || lastPlayedSquareValueO <= boardSquareValue)
            
        {
            markedSquare[WhichNumber] = playerTurn + 1; //OnClick Store Which PLayer Clicked Which Square
            gameBoardSquares[WhichNumber].image.sprite = playerGamePieces[playerTurn]; (GamePiece)gameBoardSquares[WhichNumber].interactable = false;

Comment: Thank you very kindly :)

Comment: Forgot that Zero is wild.   Adding that messes it up again.  Jeebus

Comment: Nevermind  Flipped the variables and everything works.  Thanks Again